# What is the point of DXGI_USAGE_UNORDERED_ACCESS buffer usage in swapchain?

Tags: directx-11

DirectX 11 allows swapchains with `DXGI_USAGE_UNORDERED_ACCESS`, but there is no way of setting the required CPUAccess flag ( `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE` ). 
What is the purpose of such swapchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DXGI_USAGE_UNORDERED_ACCESS` is used for writing to a resource as a UAV from a compute shader, not the CPU.